# QSlider with absolute and chunked gradient

Tags: c++, css, qt

I am trying to make a QSlider that has an absolute gradient and a chunked style in the QSlider::add-page part of the slider.

Following Style Sheet code:

```
QSlider::groove:vertical {
    background: #021017;
    BORDER-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}
QSlider::handle:vertical {
    height: 10px;
    background: #0b1707;
    border: 1px solid #46992b;
    margin: 0px -10px;
    /* expand outside the groove */

    border-radius: 5px;
}
QSlider::add-page:vertical {
    BORDER-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #0e566d;
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #46992b, stop: 0.5 #0e566d, stop: 1 #d16a4b);
}
QSlider::sub-page:vertical {
    background: #021017;
    BORDER-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #0e566d;
    margin: 0px 1px 0px 1px;
}
QSlider::handle:vertical:hover {
    background-color: #46992b;
}
```

And I get the following output:
[image]

But as I move the handle the gradient changes based on the height from the bottom of the slider to the handle. I would like the gradient to be based on the height from the bottom of the slider to the top. Meaning changing the handle position will not change the look of it.

Also is it possible to have a chunked out gradient-- like this progress bar?
[image]

Comment: Why do you write border in upper case? No different effect when keeping it consistent with the rest.

Comment: Haha. Caps lock was on... and laziness.... no good reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first question: yes, it is possible. I adjusted the style sheet you provided (uncommented things, you will notice them):

```
QSlider::groove:vertical {
    width: 10px;
    /* background: #021017;*/
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #46992b, stop: 0.5 #0e566d, stop: 1 #d16a4b);
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}
QSlider::handle:vertical {
    height: 10px;
    background: #0b1707;
    border: 1px solid #46992b;
    margin: 0px -10px;
    /* expand outside the groove */

    border-radius: 5px;
}
QSlider::add-page:vertical {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #0e566d;
    /*background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #46992b, stop: 0.5 #0e566d, stop: 1 #d16a4b);*/
}
QSlider::sub-page:vertical {
    background: #021017;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #0e566d;
    margin: 0px 1px 0px 1px;
}
QSlider::handle:vertical:hover {
    background-color: #46992b;
}
```

[image: slider with some value]
[image: slider with some more value]

*Summary:* style the `groove` with the gradient and skip the `add-page` background color.

---

For the second question, `::chunk` is not working, so *I think* it is not working with the *default* [QSlider](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qslider.html). Feel free to implement your own class, which can handle chunks.